# How to assign values from groovy to a Jenkins parameter name with space?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have  multiple jobs which have a string parameter build called " Release Context". I have coded some groovy script to automate the process, trigger the jobs and pass the parameters. But I am having some issues to escape the space in the name of parameter:

```
     def params = [new StringParameterValue( 'Release Context' , paramValue)]
     def paramsAction = new ParametersAction(params)
     jobs.scheduleBuild2(0, paramsAction)
```

The code works fine; the jobs are triggered and the values are passed when I replace the name with Release_Context but not when it contains space. Somehow I am restricted to not change the name of parameter therefore I need some help to escape the space. I have tried some ways with (/) or double (") but didn't give any result. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a Jenkins pipeline job to do this? I have had some success making  orchestrator jobs that build other jobs using the build step. It is easier than this approach I think. Not sure about the space though as I try to avoid that. Take a look at the build step https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! Yes, I have read some information about Jenkins Pipeline and agree that is better approach, but we have not implemented pipeline in our Jenkins and since I am not responsible for maintaining  Jenkins I could not make these changes and had to work on pure  groovy script. The script is already done just have to find the solution for the space problem.

Comment: I have tested similar parameter with a space in it, I don't see any issues with space. Could you provide the Jenkins logs for the error as well as the snapshot for which you are passing the value..hide info If confidential...

Comment: `+ echo 'Received Parameter value for release context:' *************
Received Parameter value for release context: *************
+ echo 'Jenkins Home:' /data/jenkins/jenkins_home  `                                                                          
                                                                                                            
 In Jenkins log not any error though, difference is when we change the name of parameter with _ the value is passed and when it has space is just empty no value @Here_2_learn

Comment: for clarification, the strings 'Release Context' while defining param and 'release context' in output are not matching, is this a typo ? or something to look into?

Comment: `echo "Received Parameter value for release context:" ${Release_Context}
echo "Jenkins Home:" ${JENKINS_HOME}
 ` I think my issue is when I echo it on execute shell, do you have any idea how to call environmental variable with space? @Here_2_learn

Comment: try this..${release\\ context}

Comment: Thanks but it shows error:  bad substitution

Comment: ask your team not to use variables with spaces..its bad way of defining and creating unnecessary issues..